# Dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'x'missing; assuming package has no files currently installed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: terminal, upgrade, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with lubunut desktop environment. I had the following problem for more than 3 days when I do `apt-get upgrade`. I don't know what is problem means and how to solve.

Note: 3 days before I try upgrade Linux-header-4.4.66, but it showed an error. I deleted it. Now, I'm back to Linux-header-4.4.64, which worked fine before.

```
Error on sudo apt-get dist-upgrade (only last 15 line of 500+ line error):

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxcb-xkb1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libvorbis-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavahi-core7:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 37151 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches to /usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2 by libgtk-3-bin'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches.gtk2' with
  different file '/usr/sbin/update-icon-caches', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem at last night. If you know Chinese, you can [read this solution on my blog](http://fitzeng.org/2017/11/04/linuxDpkgBug/). I'll detail it here with my poor English.

- Create three files in you desktop or anywhere you want.

  ```
  fix.sh
  txt
  fixit.py
  ```
- Add contents in these files

  1. *fix.sh*: Just an Empty file.
  2. *txt*: Copy your log into this file with '\n' to separate each line. Just like this:

     ```
     dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxcb-xkb1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed 
     dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libvorbis-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
     ```
  3. *fixit.py*: fill the file with the following contents.

     ```python
     #!/usr/bin/env python
         # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
         __author__ = 'Fitzeng'
         import re
         def main():
             fix = open('fix.sh', 'w+')
             for line in open("txt"):
                 pkg = re.match(re.compile('''dpkg: warning: files list file for package '(.+)' '''), line)
                 if pkg:
                     cmd = "sudo apt-get install --reinstall " + pkg.group(1)
                     fix.write(cmd + '\n')
         if __name__ == "__main__":
             main()
     ```
- Execute these file.

  ```
  chmod 777 *
  python fixit.py
  ./fix.sh
  ```

OK, problem solved. Actually, you'll find you could alternately just reinstall these packages. So, you can fix it in many ways.

Comment: The type of answer you've provided here is desired on Stack Overflow. Good job. I've edited your post to improve the formatting and grammar. More importantly, I made it explicit that the link you provided is to your own blog. When you link to your own site you need to explicitly state that it's your site. You had only made that implicit. For more information, see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion). In this post, that was a minor issue, but it's one which I wanted to make sure you're aware of for the future.

Comment: THX for your suggestions, this answer is not self-promotion. you can see this is my first answer in Stack Overflow. I just want to share my ideas with others, so I didn't know these operations were not allowed in this platform. I'll correct it in the future, thank you again.

Comment: I didn't thing you were posting this as self promotion. However, there are guidelines of which I felt you should be informed. The type of answer you've provided here is certainly something that we desire to see on Stack Overflow. This answer is self contained and provides a full answer to the question. It's *far* above what we see when someone is just trying to post self promotion. Having a link to your own blog is fine, as long as you explicitly state that it's yours and the answer is complete without the need to click through to your blog. What you've done here is good. Please do more.